# php if/else with concatenation

Tags: php, if-statement, concatenation

I have this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in /home/user/public_html/page.php on line 132

this is the code:

```
<td><b>".$row['extension']."</b></td>
<td>".$row['curprefix']." ".if {($row['msetupfee'] =='-1.00') { echo 'N/D'; } else {$row['msetupfee'];}."</td>
<td>".$row['curprefix']." ".$row['qsetupfee']."</td>
```

the line 132 is:

```
 <td>".$row['curprefix']." ".if {($row['msetupfee'] =='-1.00') { echo 'N/D'; } else {$row['msetupfee'];}."</td>
```

Comment: You can't put a control structure in the middle of an echo statement. Take it out and save the result in a variable and then echo out the value of that variable.

Comment: `if` inside `echo` is something not possible that way

Comment: John Conde and Royal Bg: yes he can do that. He needs [ternary operators](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators).

Comment: the if is also falsy constructed : if {( ... what is that { doing there?

Comment: Why not consider echos inside if/else instead of if/else inside echoes?

Comment: `<td>".$row['curprefix']." ".($row['msetupfee'] =='-1.00'?'N/D':$row['msetupfee'])."</td>`

Comment: **Hint:** Use an IDE and you'll never have syntax errors again!

Comment: @Panique: An IDE is overrated. An editor with color coding is enough, like Notepad++. For example, when I switched from Dreamweaver I noticed I don't know css syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't put an IF right in the middle of concatenating a string. Either do the IF before and pass the value where you had the IF

```
if ($row['msetupfee'] =='-1.00') {
    $v = "N/D";
}
else {
    $v = $row['msetupfee'];
}

// 
// Other code
//
..."<td>" . $row['curprefix'] . " " . $v ."</td>"...
```

OR do this...

```
..."<td>" . $row['curprefix'] . " " . ($row['msetupfee'] =='-1.00' ? 'N/D' : $row['msetupfee']) . "</td>"...
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're seeing but I put `if ($row...`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a ternary statement to achieve this:

```
<?php 
    if {($row['msetupfee'] =='-1.00') { echo 'N/D'; } else {$row['msetupfee'];}
?>
```

becomes

```
<?php 
    echo (($row['msetupfee'] =='-1.00') ?'N/D':$row['msetupfee']);
?>
```

So:

```
echo "<td>".$row['curprefix']." ".if {($row['msetupfee'] =='-1.00') { echo 'N/D'; } else {$row['msetupfee'];}."</td>"
```

becomes

```
echo "<td>".$row['curprefix']." ".(($row['msetupfee'] =='-1.00') ?'N/D':$row['msetupfee'])."</td>"
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want a if in your string, do with '?'

```
"<td>".$row['curprefix']." ". $row['msetupfee'] == '-1.00' ?  'N/D' : $row['msetupfee']."</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not place an if statement inside the middle of a string concatenation. You could have your if statement outside and change a variable based on the conditions, then print that variable inside your concatenation.

```
<?php
$vb;

if ($row['msetupfee'] =='-1.00') { 
    $vb = 'N/D'; 
} else {
    $vb = $row['msetupfee'];
}

echo "<td>".$row['curprefix']." ".$vb</td>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have omitted `echo`s when posting code, I guess what you were trying to do was this:

```
<?php
echo "<td><b>".$row['extension']."</b></td>
<td>".$row['curprefix']." ".if {($row['msetupfee'] =='-1.00') { echo 'N/D'; } else {$row['msetupfee'];}."</td>
<td>".$row['curprefix']." ".$row['qsetupfee']."</td>";
?>
```

### Problems

- You cannot use control structures inside `echo` statements.
- Even if you could, your `if` statement had syntax errors: `if {(condition) { ... }` is wrong! It should be `if (condition) { ... }`

There are several things you can do.

### Take the control structure to another line

```
<?php
echo "<td><b>".$row['extension']."</b></td><td>".$row['curprefix'];

if ($row['msetupfee'] =='-1.00') {
    echo 'N/D';
} else {
    $row['msetupfee'];
}

echo "</td><td>".$row['curprefix']." ".$row['qsetupfee']."</td>";
?>
```

### Use a function

```
<?php
function getSetupFee($msetupfee) {
    if ($msetupfee =='-1.00') {
        return 'N/D';
    } else {
        return $msetupfee;
    }
}

echo "<td><b>".$row['extension']."</b></td><td>".$row['curprefix'].
     getSetupFee($row['msetupfee']).
     "</td><td>".$row['curprefix']." ".$row['qsetupfee']."</td>";
?>
```

### Get the logic out of markup: *Recommended*

You get these kind of problems because you have mixed HTML and code together.

The way you have mixed markup (HTML) and business logic is practically unreadable. It would be good to separate markup and logic. Also, it is a good practice to retain the hierarchical structure of HTML.

The *simplest* way you can do this is this:

```
<td>
    <b><?php echo $row['extension']; ?></b>
</td>
<td>
    <?php
        echo $row['curprefix'];

        if ($row['msetupfee'] == '-1.00') {
            echo 'N/D';
        } else {
            $row['msetupfee'];
        }
    ?>
</td>
<td>
    <?php echo $row['curprefix']." ".$row['qsetupfee']. ?>
</td>
```

In this re-factored code, it is immediately evident that you are creating three table cells, and which values your are printing inside the cells.